# How to validate angular from for custom input component

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular12

I am trying to validate custom input component in angular.
I have created custom input component and also passing control name as a input property to app-input component then trying to validate it. Not working properly. How to validate custom input component in angular?

app.component.html:

```
 <div class="register-form">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Full Name</label>
      <app-input [controlName]="'fullname'"></app-input>
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.fullname.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.fullname.errors.required">Fullname is required</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
form: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
{
fullname: \['', Validators.required\]  
}
);
}

get f(): { \[key: string\]: AbstractControl } {
return this.form.controls;
}

onSubmit(): void {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.form.invalid) {
return;
}

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value, null, 2));

}

onReset(): void {
this.submitted = false;
this.form.reset();
}
}
```

input.component.html:

```
      <input type="text" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control" \>
```

input.component.ts:

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()
public controlName: string;

constructor(@Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

get form(): FormGroup {
return this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
}

get control(): FormControl {
return this.form.get(this.controlName) as FormControl;
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-fh18ef?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Trying to validate input text field by passing form control name from app component. but not working.

Comment: I think you want to make a ControlValueAccessor with your input.

There is a lot of tutorial like here : https://sreyaj.dev/custom-form-controls-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular

Comment: @Mael: I am new for angular. Can you edit my stackblitz?